# Multiple views and data templates binding to the same viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I am working on a usercontrol that is switching between two views. The usercontrol is bind/bound to a view model. I am able to switch between the two views but unable to bind to the properties of the mother viewmodel. below is the code

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DoubleViewKey" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ArithmeticViewModel}">
        <views:ArithmeticDoubleFloatView></views:ArithmeticDoubleFloatView>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerViewKey" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ArithmeticViewModel}">
        <views:ArithmeticInt32View></views:ArithmeticInt32View>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I am able to switch between the two views, the controls are also rendered properly. But they are empty even if the ArithmeticViewModel properties are not null. I hope my question makes sense, and thank you in advance for helping.

Comment: If you have a problem with your `Binding Path`s, then how about showing them? There is no problem with your `DataTemplate`s.

Comment: Show the code inside ArithmeticInt32View

Comment: yes sorry it was a silly mistake. i was missing bindings and a data context. thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

When you have a child `UserControl` that you want to data bind to a parent view model, you can do that using a [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). What you put in your `RelativeSource Binding` will depend on how you have set up your project.

As an example, let's say that your parent view is the `MainWindow.xaml` file and you have correctly set a valid parent view model to the `Window.DataContext` property. Controls inside any child views declared in the `MainWindow` XAML can then access the parent view model like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.TextValue, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MainWindow}}}" />
```

It is important to start the `Binding.Path` value with `DataContext.` because the property is in the object that is set as the `DataContext` of the `Window`, so it would not work without this.

Comment: yes sorry it was a silly mistake. i was missing bindings and a data context. thank you for helping